# Any open set shares boundary with a discrete set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

**Claim:** Let $X$ be a metric space and let $U\subset X$ be open. Then there exists a discrete set $A\subset X$ such that $\partial A = \partial U$.

**Approach thus far:** Since this statement is about existence, it is clear to me that I need to invoke SOME kind of choice here. My current attempts involve making open covers of $\partial U$, using paracomactness of metric spaces to refine the cover, and then make some sort of clever selection (clever selection pending*) using the Axiom of Choice. One of the proofs of this claim, which I failed to digest, included a use of Zorn's Lemma. I have been trying to come up with clever selections for a while now, but to no avail.

**Here are some sloppy definitions that I haven't done much with:** Define $C_\epsilon$ to be a refinement guaranteed by paracompactness of $X$ of $\lbrace B_\epsilon (x) | x\in \partial U\rbrace$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $A_n$ to be the selection, by the axiom of choice, of points from $C_{1/n}\setminus C_{1/(n+1)}$. This selection could be empty as I see it, because I do not know if there is a way to tell if any of the $C_{1/n}\setminus C_{1/(n+1)}$ are nonempty. The idea of using the epsilon covers was to ensure that we could force points to get close to the boundary. The idea behind using paracompactness is to ensure that once we make a selection of points from a cover, the points aren't too close and don't cluster to form boundary that isn't $\partial U$.

If at all possible, I don't want an answer or a proof of **Claim**. I would, however, very much appreciate guidance or suggestions about where to go with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a quite complete answer [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/26.pdf).

If you know about paracompactness, the final part is shortest:

Let $A = \partial U$, $U$ open. $U_x = U \cap B\left(x, \frac{d(x,A)}{2}\right)$ for $x \in U$. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a locally finite refinement of the cover $\{U_x: x \in U\}$. For each $V \in \mathcal{V}$, pick $p_V \in V$, then the set $D = \{p_V: V \in \mathcal{V} \}$ is discrete and has $\partial D= D' = A$.